# Are genealogical questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I recently came across some information that indicated a spike in the usage of my given name (Mark) in the 1960s, and wanted to see if there was a cause for it.

Would such questions be on-topic here? What about other genealogical questions, like clan/family movements and such?

Answer (score 3):

I think it would depend entirely on how you phrase the question. For example, if you asked "Why did the name (Mark) see a spike in usage during the 1960s", that would not be accepted. That would be a question that invites specualtion and opinion, rather than a clear and concise answer.

Questions about clan or culture migrations would be on topic generally, but again, it depends on how you ask the question. Just be sure that you phrase it in a way that invites an actual answer rather than opinions or discussions.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone here at "History" is interested in genealogy, there currently (as I write this) is a proposal for a StackExchange site for "Genealogy and Family History" at Area51.

If you're interested, I encourage you pop over there and "Commit" to the proposal and help the site get started. You all have 200+ Rep and you would very much help it reach what it needs to get to Beta.

The site is at: [http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502](http://bit.ly/U3vnDX)

I am hoping that by the time you read this, the Genealogy and Family History Q&A site is already Beta, or maybe is already permanent. If so, we'll welcome you.

I'm sure many of our genealogy buffs will also be coming to join you at your history site.

Comment: Check [the top of the commit list](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502?phase=commitment&committers=userreputation#tab-top) :P

Comment: I was quite aware that you joined us, Mark. That's what attracted me to your post on genealogy here at History. I wanted to let the Meta-Historians who might be interested in Genealogy know about our new Genealogy Q&A proposal, but not in a spammy way. :-)  p.s. Do you have any contacts who might be interested?

Comment: Would you mind updating this to reflect that it is now in public beta? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Genealogical questions outside of the History scope can be directed to [Genealogy.SE](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/).

Like @StevenDrennon, I think making a history-related question will demand the context of where/what(/how?) historical matters relating to more than one member of family/clan.  The spread of the 'Huns', etc.